# GLSL fragment shader on different video cards

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader

I'm trying to convert a 12-bit YUV frame(YUV420P) to a 24-bit RGB frame with a GLSL shader.
On Nvidia video cards it is working, but on ATI video cards it is working too, but works not correct. The image doesn't draw correctly. The colors are different and the image is a quarter of the full size.

Here is code of shader:

```
uniform sampler2DRect y_texture, u_texture, v_texture;
uniform float imageHeight;

void main(void) {
    float sx, sy, r, g, b, y, u, v;
    sx = gl_TexCoord[0].x;
    sy = imageHeight - gl_TexCoord[0].y;
    y = texture2DRect(y_texture, vec2(sx / 2.0, sy / 2.0)).r;
    u = texture2DRect(u_texture, vec2(sx / 2.0, sy / 2.0)).r;
    v = texture2DRect(v_texture, vec2(sx / 2.0, sy / 2.0)).r;
    y = 1.1643 * (y - 0.0625);
    u = u - 0.5;
    v = v - 0.5;
    r = y + 1.5958 * v;
    g = y - 0.39173 * u - 0.8129 * v;
    b = y + 2.017 * u;
    gl_FragColor = vec4(r, g, b, 1.0);
}
```

How can I modify it (or create new)?

Here is sample code:

```
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_ARB);

//FrameHeight
int i_imageHeight = glGetUniformLocation(handleProgram, "imageHeight");
glUniform1f(i_imageHeight, (float)frameHeight);

//U
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
int i_u = glGetUniformLocationARB(handleProgram, "u_texture");
glUniform1iARB(i_u, 1);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_ARB, 1);

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_ARB, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_ARB, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_DECAL);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_ARB, 0, GL_LUMINANCE, frameWidth / 2, frameHeight / 2, 0, GL_LUMINANCE, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, uFrameData);

//V
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE2);
int i_v = glGetUniformLocationARB(handleProgram, "v_texture");
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_ARB, 2);
glUniform1iARB(i_v, 2);

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_ARB, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_ARB, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_DECAL);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_ARB, 0, GL_LUMINANCE, frameWidth / 2, frameHeight / 2, 0, GL_LUMINANCE, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, vFrameData);

//Y
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
int i_y = glGetUniformLocationARB(handleProgram, "y_texture");
glUniform1iARB(i_y, 3);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_ARB, 0);

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_ARB, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_ARB, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_DECAL);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_ARB, 0, GL_LUMINANCE, frameWidth, frameHeight, 0, GL_LUMINANCE, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, yFrameData);

//Draw
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2i(0, 0); glVertex2i(0, 0);
    glTexCoord2i(frameWidth, 0); glVertex2i(this->width, 0);
    glTexCoord2i(frameWidth, frameHeight); glVertex2i(this->width, this->height);
    glTexCoord2i(0, frameHeight); glVertex2i(0, this->height);
glEnd();

glFlush();
SwapBuffers(hDC);
```

Comment: Please also post the host code. Maybe you're using GL_TEXTURE_2D instead of GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_ARB there?

Comment: I've posted code... Also in shader: 
y = texture2DRect(y_texture, vec2(sx / 2.0, sy / 2.0)).r;
this line for ATI cards.
In nVidia cards:
y = texture2DRect(y_texture, vec2(sx, sy)).r;

Comment: Fine, but what do you mean by "not correct"?

Comment: Image draws not correct... Another colors and image size is 1/4 of full size...

Comment: I've tested this program and shader on this computer, but on Linux(Ununtu)... Result - picture draws correct! Strange...

Comment: +1 I was struggling with a YV12 shader I wrote for a custom video player because the resulting images were slightly different from a snapshot taken by VLC, this was highly visible on images that were heavy on Red. The constants you used in your shader solved my problem. Thanks.

Comment: Are you outputting the compiler messages? If no, do so. It's impossible to write shaders without compiler messages. 2nd thing: Do all casts explicitly (like float to int for example). 3rd thing: Replace variables like "1.0" with "1.0f". ATI cards always complain about that kind of stuff. Does the ATI card support texture rectangles? You also shouldn't generate your own texture ids. generate them using glGenTextures.

Comment: Woops. Ignore my line "Replace variables like "1.0" with "1.0f".". That just applies to OpenCL, not OpenGL.

Answer (score 0):

You are using textures incorrectly. Nowhere I can see you creating the texture objects (`glGenTextures`). You need to first generate 3 texture objects, and pass those inside `glBindTexture`. Instead, what you are doing is using 0, 1, and 2 indices, which is also incorrect because 0 is an index for a non-existent texture. I suspect OpenGL to give you error codes on any attempt to change 0 texture state. So add some `glError`() checks between calls. Technically, your program is an example of "undefined behavior" on GL, so the difference in execution by various HW/drivers should be expected (until you fix it).

For your reference, the texture management should look like this:

```
GLuint textures[3];
glGenTextures(3,textures);
...
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_ARB, textures[1]);
//initialize state of t1
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_ARB, textures[2]);
//initialize state of t2
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_ARB, textures[0]);
//initialize state of t0
```

Note that your call to glUniform and glActiveTexture are still correct, so no need to fix them.